# Graphing perpendicular offsets in a least squares regression plot in R

Tags: r, statistics, plot, linear-regression, least-squares

I'm interested in making a plot with a least squares regression line and line segments connecting the datapoints to the regression line as illustrated here in the graphic called perpendicular offsets:
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastSquaresFitting.html
[image]
<sub>(from MathWorld - A Wolfram Web Resource: [wolfram.com](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/images/eps-gif/LeastSquaresOffsets_1000.gif))</sub>

I have the plot and regression line done here:

```
## Dataset from http://www.apsnet.org/education/advancedplantpath/topics/RModules/doc1/04_Linear_regression.html

## Disease severity as a function of temperature

# Response variable, disease severity
diseasesev<-c(1.9,3.1,3.3,4.8,5.3,6.1,6.4,7.6,9.8,12.4)

# Predictor variable, (Centigrade)
temperature<-c(2,1,5,5,20,20,23,10,30,25)

## For convenience, the data may be formatted into a dataframe
severity <- as.data.frame(cbind(diseasesev,temperature))

## Fit a linear model for the data and summarize the output from function lm()
severity.lm <- lm(diseasesev~temperature,data=severity)

# Take a look at the data
plot(
 diseasesev~temperature,
        data=severity,
        xlab="Temperature",
        ylab="% Disease Severity",
        pch=16,
        pty="s",
        xlim=c(0,30),
        ylim=c(0,30)
)
abline(severity.lm,lty=1)
title(main="Graph of % Disease Severity vs Temperature")
```

Should I use some kind of for loop and segments http://www.iiap.res.in/astrostat/School07/R/html/graphics/html/segments.html to do the perpendicular offsets?  Is there a more efficient way?  Please provide an example if possible.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You first need to figure out the coordinates for the base of the perpendicular segments, then call the `segments` function which can take vectors of coordinates as inputs (no need for a loop).

```
perp.segment.coord <- function(x0, y0, lm.mod){
 #finds endpoint for a perpendicular segment from the point (x0,y0) to the line
 # defined by lm.mod as y=a+b*x
  a <- coef(lm.mod)[1]  #intercept
  b <- coef(lm.mod)[2]  #slope
  x1 <- (x0+b*y0-a*b)/(1+b^2)
  y1 <- a + b*x1
  list(x0=x0, y0=y0, x1=x1, y1=y1)
}
```

Now just call segments:

```
ss <- perp.segment.coord(temperature, diseasesev, severity.lm)
do.call(segments, ss)
#which is the same as:
segments(x0=ss$x0, x1=ss$x1, y0=ss$y0, y1=ss$y1)
```

Note that the results will not look perpendicular unless you ensure that the x-unit and y-unit of your plot have the same apparent length (isometric scales). You can do that by using `pty="s"` to get a square plot and set `xlim` and `ylim` to the same range.