# Adding orthogonal regression line in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, orthogonal

I have plotted a scatter graph in R, comparing expected to observed values,using the following script:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)


r<-read_csv("Uni/MSci/Project/DATA/new data sheets/comparisons/for comarison 
graphs/R Regression/GAcAs.csv")
x<-r[1]
y<-r[2]

ggplot()+geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y))+ 
scale_size_area() + 
xlab("Expected") +
ylab("Observed") +
ggtitle("G - As x Ac")+ xlim(0, 40)+ylim(0, 40)
```

My plot is as follows:

[image]

I then want to add an orthogonal regression line (as there could be errors in both the expected and observed values). I have calculated the beta value using the following:

```
v <- prcomp(cbind(x,y))$rotation
beta <- v[2,1]/v[1,1]
```

Is there a way to add an orthogonal regression line to my plot?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ggplot2: How to plot an orthogonal regression line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26995923/ggplot2-how-to-plot-an-orthogonal-regression-line)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Borrowed from this [blog post](https://onunicornsandgenes.blog/2013/05/31/how-to-draw-the-line-with-ggplot2/) & this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30399576/786542). Basically, you will need `Deming` function from `MethComp` or `prcomp` from `stats` packages together with a custom function `perp.segment.coord`. Below is an example taken from above mentioned blog post.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(MethComp)

data(airquality)
airquality <- na.exclude(airquality)

# Orthogonal, total least squares or Deming regression
deming <- Deming(y=airquality$Wind, x=airquality$Temp)[1:2]
deming  
#>  Intercept      Slope 
#> 24.8083259 -0.1906826

# Check with prcomp {stats}
r <- prcomp( ~ airquality$Temp + airquality$Wind )
slope <- r$rotation[2,1] / r$rotation[1,1]
slope   
#> [1] -0.1906826

intercept <- r$center[2] - slope*r$center[1]
intercept
#> airquality$Wind 
#>        24.80833

# https://stackoverflow.com/a/30399576/786542
perp.segment.coord <- function(x0, y0, ortho){
  # finds endpoint for a perpendicular segment from the point (x0,y0) to the line
  # defined by ortho as y = a + b*x
  a <- ortho[1]  # intercept
  b <- ortho[2]  # slope
  x1 <- (x0 + b*y0 - a*b)/(1 + b^2)
  y1 <- a + b*x1
  list(x0=x0, y0=y0, x1=x1, y1=y1)
}

perp.segment <- perp.segment.coord(airquality$Temp, airquality$Wind, deming)
perp.segment <- as.data.frame(perp.segment)
    
# plot
plot.y <- ggplot(data = airquality, aes(x = Temp, y = Wind)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_abline(intercept = deming[1],
              slope = deming[2]) +
  geom_segment(data = perp.segment, 
               aes(x = x0, y = y0, xend = x1, yend = y1), 
               colour = "blue") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Created on 2018-03-19 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 2):

The `MethComp` package seems to be no longer maintained (was removed from CRAN). 
[Russel88/COEF](https://github.com/Russel88/COEF) allows to use `stat_`/`geom_summary` with `method="tls"` to add an orthogonal regression line.

Based on this and [wikipedia:Deming_regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deming_regression) I created the following functions, which allow to use noise ratios other than 1:

```r
deming.fit <- function(x, y, noise_ratio = sd(y)/sd(x)) {
  if(missing(noise_ratio) || is.null(noise_ratio)) noise_ratio <- eval(formals(sys.function(0))$noise_ratio) # this is just a complicated way to write `sd(y)/sd(x)`
  delta <-  noise_ratio^2
  x_name <- deparse(substitute(x))

  s_yy <- var(y)
  s_xx <- var(x)
  s_xy <- cov(x, y)
  beta1 <- (s_yy - delta*s_xx + sqrt((s_yy - delta*s_xx)^2 + 4*delta*s_xy^2)) / (2*s_xy)
  beta0 <- mean(y) - beta1 * mean(x) 

  res <- c(beta0 = beta0, beta1 = beta1)
  names(res) <- c("(Intercept)", x_name)
  class(res) <- "Deming"
  res
}

deming <- function(formula, data, R = 100, noise_ratio = NULL, ...){
  ret <- boot::boot(
    data = model.frame(formula, data), 
    statistic = function(data, ind) {
      data <- data[ind, ]
      args <- rlang::parse_exprs(colnames(data))
      names(args) <- c("y", "x")
      rlang::eval_tidy(rlang::expr(deming.fit(!!!args, noise_ratio = noise_ratio)), data, env = rlang::current_env())
    },
    R=R
  )
  class(ret) <- c("Deming", class(ret))
  ret  
}

predictdf.Deming <- function(model, xseq, se, level) {
  pred <- as.vector(tcrossprod(model$t0, cbind(1, xseq)))
  if(se) {
    preds <- tcrossprod(model$t, cbind(1, xseq))
    data.frame(
      x = xseq,
      y = pred,
      ymin = apply(preds, 2, function(x) quantile(x, probs = (1-level)/2)),
      ymax = apply(preds, 2, function(x) quantile(x, probs = 1-((1-level)/2)))
    )
  } else {
    return(data.frame(x = xseq, y = pred))
  }
}

# unrelated hlper function to create a nicer plot:
fix_plot_limits <- function(p) p + coord_cartesian(xlim=ggplot_build(p)$layout$panel_params[[1]]$x.range, ylim=ggplot_build(p)$layout$panel_params[[1]]$y.range)
```

Demonstration:

```r
library(ggplot2)

#devtools::install_github("Russel88/COEF")
library(COEF)

fix_plot_limits(
    ggplot(data.frame(x = (1:5) + rnorm(100), y = (1:5) + rnorm(100)*2), mapping = aes(x=x, y=y)) +
      geom_point()
    ) +
  geom_smooth(method=deming, aes(color="deming"), method.args = list(noise_ratio=2)) +
  geom_smooth(method=lm, aes(color="lm")) +
  geom_smooth(method = COEF::tls, aes(color="tls"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-12-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This is the best answer - as it is the only one which allows you to use geom_smooth (which allows for faceting etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand the question, but if you want line segments to show errors along both x and y axis, you can do this using `geom_segment`.

Something like this:

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10), y = rnorm(10), w = rnorm(10, sd=.1))

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, xend = x, yend = y)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_segment(aes(x = x - w, xend = x + w)) +
    geom_segment(aes(y = y - w, yend = y + w))
```

Comment: I basically want to add a regression line, however I want orthogonal regression line, not linear regression

Comment: I don't understand what that means... to be orthogonal, surely you need at least two lines?